# Python: How to interpret and improve predict_proba() in RandomForest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

So I am using sci-kit learns RandomForestClassifier to classify data of astronomical sources into three categories. To make my question more straightforward, I used only two sources in my test set and got `predict_prob()` scores with:

```
predictions = rf_model.predict(data_test)
probab =  rf_model.predict_proba(data_test)

print(probab)
print('True Classifications:', classif_test.values)
print('Predictions', predictions)
```

giving me the following:

```
[[0.29 0.69 0.02]
 [0.08 0.92 0.  ]]
True Classifications: ['HMXB' 'AGN']
Predictions ['HMXB' 'HMXB']
```

where the class order is `[AGN, HMXB, SNR]`. The problem is one of these predictions is wrong while the other is correct.

I have a few questions. 
(a) how do I tell which `predict_prob()` score corresponds to the wrong prediction?
(b) What exactly is `predict_prob()` describing? Is it how likely the model's classification is believed to be correct or something else? 
(b) What does a high probability score for a class that leads to an inaccurate prediction mean? Is my data set simply too small, or is there ways to improve the predicted probabilities?

So for my data, I have 46 HMXB, 17 AGN, and 3 SNR. Each source has three attributes with it. I know this is a small data set, but what I am wondering is whether it is too small for a RandomForest or other machine learning algorithms to give accurate results.

Comment: *how do I tell which predict_prob() score corresponds to the wrong prediction?* Not sure what you are asking here ........... *Is my data set simply too small* You should add some info about your dataset and if possible some sample data too

Comment: So both sources had `predict_prob()` score highest for HMXBs. But one of those HMXBs was an AGN.  Does the 0.69 or 0.92 score correspond to the wrong prediction? Sorry for the unconcise questions, machine learning is still new to me and my vocabulary is lacking.

Comment: I can spot 2 problems in your dataset. One you already know, your dataset is too small to get properly trained and your data is imbalanced. You can search for *Data imbalance problem in machine learning*

Answer (score 3):

For the question (b) What exactly is predict_prob() describing?
The ***predict_prob()*** will give the probability of the labels. 
for example if you have three labels ['A','B','C'] and the predict_prob() gives [0.29,0.69,.02], means the outcome of that particular data has 0.29 probability of becoming 'A', 0.69 probability of being 'B', 0.02 probability of being 'C'.

For the question (a) how do I tell which predict_prob() score corresponds to the wrong prediction?
From the output you posted

```
[[0.29 0.69 0.02]
 [0.08 0.92 0.  ]]
Predictions ['HMXB' 'HMXB']
```

It clearly tells that the second item in each list corresponds to 'HMXB'. And the other two probabilities (first item and last item) we need to look at the data and tell.

Yes, you are data is small and quite imbalanced. Because you have lot of samples for 'HMXB' when compared to the other two. Try to get more samples for the other labels aswell.

Comment: I understand that `[0.29 0.69 0.02]` corresponds to a predicted HMXB, similar to the other list. But one of these has an actual true classification of AGN. Does `[0.29 0.69 0.02]` give the class predictions corresponding to the true AGN or does the other list?

Comment: [0.29 0.69 0.02] in this only 0.69 corresponds to HMXB.